# A new transaction is created in Camel route for each call to DataService

Tags: spring, jdbc, transactions, apache-camel

I have 2 dataserive both which call 2 different stored procedure(which updates some table). I have used DataSourceTransactionManager on the dataservice to cater this request. 
These dataservices are called from a single route(transacted) in business service which uses Platform transaction manager with Policy as PROPAGATION_REQUIRED.

The problem is the transaction is not persisted across these two dataservice calls i.e if the seocond call fails it rollback just the second call , while the first data service call is committed. I want the both the dataservice call to be part of the same transaction.

below is my configuration:

```
 <bean id="required" class="org.apache.camel.spring.spi.SpringTransactionPolicy">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="txManager"/>
    <property name="propagationBehaviorName" value="PROPAGATION_REQUIRED"/>
  </bean>

 <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager"/>


<route>
  <from uri="direct:businessservice"/>
  <transacted ref="required"/>
  <to uri="DataService?updateCustomer"/>
 <to uri="DataService?updateaccount"/>
</route>
```

I want the above route entirely to be one transaction.

Comment: What does DataService do? You would need to make sure whatever it is, that it support TX, and that its hooked up into the Spring txManager.

Comment: Data Service is call to DB2 Store procedure to update some data.on the database side i have the used spring  DataSourceTransactionManager and it should handle the transaction.But the problem is it doesnt handle throughout the route just handles individual data call.

Comment: You must use the same TX manager, eg PlatformTransactionManager and not DataSource. eg your problem is not Camel, but how to configure TX in Spring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cluas you are correct i had to use the same transaction manager across.

Using the DatasourceTxManager on the datasource source side and then exposing it through OSGI solved the issue.

Comment: I see you are using spring in an OSGI container, just out of curiosity, are you using spring-dm ? thank you